# Unable to download "prophet" in the Rstudio Instance in Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, package, facebook-prophet

Tried downloading the prophet but it says unavailable on the present R version 3.6.3. Updated it to 4.0.0 and still the same issue. Please suggest! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running this prior, this worked for me when installing prophet into Databricks:

```
Sys.setenv(DOWNLOAD_STATIC_LIBV8 = 1)
remotes::install_github("jeroen/V8")
devtools::install_version("rstantools", version = "2.0.0")
install.packages('prophet')
```